# create a rewrite condition for following URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have following URL

```
http://localhost/dyescan/pair_pixel_filter?type=0
```

i want rewrite Rule and write condition for it, so far i have done this

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dyescan/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+([^.]+)\.php\?type=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2.html? [R=301,L]

#Make sure it's not an actual file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#Make sure its not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
#Rewrite the request to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
</ifModule>
```

what happens here is that i get my desired page but, i now cannot access my CSS libraries also if there is another xpage some thing like this

```
localhost/dyescan/sompage.php?test=1
```

it redirects me to the appache default page. what is the workaround for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2.html? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: there is a small problem in my URL, i cannot access any other page i am redirected to phpinfo(); page, can you please tell me what am i doing wrong there?

Comment: Add a `<base href="/dyescan/" />` to your page headers. It's because all of your links are relative URLs and you've just changed the base to `/dyescan/sompage/blah/` instead of just `/dyescan/`.

Comment: another work around for this can be if i change `RewriteBase /dyescan/` to `RewriteBase /`?

Comment: @temp-learn no, that has nothing to do with the URL's that are in your page content. The RewriteBase just tells the rules in the htaccess file what relative base to use, it doesn't tell the browser anything.